# Overriding a service in bUnit

Tags: bunit

I have a `TestContext` Setup() method that adds all the services my pages need. Very nice having one place that sets up all 30+ services.

Sometimes I need a different mock service for a test. So I need to replace the default service.

I've tried setting the specific one after I call my `Setup()` and that works. Is this supported? That the last `Services.AddSingleton()` is used? Or is this just how the code is written at present and it could change?

I tried calling `Services.Remove<IMyService>()` but that gives me a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just register the service in your test. The latest registered services is returned, unless a component gets an `IEnumerable<IMyService>` injected, then all registered `IMyService`s gets injected.

Comment: I figured that was it. But always better to check for the occasional time I have the wrong assumption. Thanks.